# Is there a significant performance impact between pipeline and straight resolvers?

Tags: aws-appsync

Let's assume I have an AppSync API.

This API has one resolver which consists of a simple `GetItem` operation on a DynamoDB table.

Now if for some obscure reason I wanted to convert that single operation resolver into a pipeline resolver (with still the same operation and nothing significant in `before` and `after` mapping templates), it would probably be fair to assume that there would be some performance hit between the straight operation resolver and the pipeline resolver.

Now I was wondering about the scale of that performance hit: is it going to be negligible, noticeable, or orders of magnitude ?

Answer (score 0):

The performance hit should be linear in the sense that if you have a resolver accessing a data source with a request and response mapping template compared to the performance of 2 functions doing similar work with a request and response mapping template each, accessing 2 data sources (each function accessing a data source), this should roughly take twice the time the first resolver takes.